# Error Deleting Named Range on Windows 10 Excel 2013 - Older Versions Work Fine

Tags: excel, windows-10, named-ranges, vba

I'm having a problem that I don't really know how to fix. I have a code that runs perfectly in Windows 7 Excel 2010 and always has. In the last few weeks it has developed an error but only when running in Windows 10 Excel 2013.

Basically the below code copies some data sheets to a new workbook in order to strip the VBA out (as this is blocked by company filters). It then loops through all the objects and names and deletes them before sending it via Outlook

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click()
'---------------------Create the email spreadsheet---------------------------------
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim NewBook         As Workbook
Dim EEName As String
Dim nm As Name

EEName = Range("ForeNameCell").Value & " " & Range("SurnameCell").Value
FPath = VBA.Environ("temp") & "\" 'file path to store the copy of the sheet
FName = "NS Form - " & EEName & " " & VBA.Format(VBA.Now(), "mm_dd_yyyy hh mm AMPM")

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 'create a new workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("contract Print Out").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1) 'copy over the printoutallfields sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oracle Data").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1) 'copy over the printoutallfields sheet
'copy and paste special data in new workbook to remove formula
NewBook.Sheets("contract Print Out").Cells.Copy
NewBook.Sheets("contract Print Out").Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
NewBook.Sheets("Oracle Data").Cells.Copy
NewBook.Sheets("Oracle Data").Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'remove back buttons
Dim myshape As Shape
For Each myshape In NewBook.Sheets("contract Print Out").Shapes
    myshape.Delete
Next myshape
For Each myshape In NewBook.Sheets("Oracle Data").Shapes
    myshape.Delete
Next myshape
'remove links and named ranges
Application.Calculation = xlManual
On Error Resume Next
For Each nm In NewBook.Names
    nm.Delete ' This line now errors in W10 E2013
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'NewBook.Sheets("PrintOutallFields").Name = "User Data" 'rename it in the destination workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'turn off overwrite prompt so that it will just overwrite
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & FName 'save the file
DoEvents
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'turn overwrite prompt back on
NewBook.Close
```

The error that appears is below and when I query the name it is trying to delete it comes up with #NAME?. Every single name seems to appear this way to the code as when I skip ahead and try to go to the next nm, the same thing happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I forgot to mention the reason we delete the names from the workbook is due to them always referring the original file. This causes issues when we receive it as the original would of course, always be on the customers PC.

My guess is MS in their eternal wisdom, pushed an update which breaks VBA between versions ... AGAIN! I've had to fix a few of these already but I am stumped by this one.

Comment: Is it visible in the Name Manager? Can you supply a screenshot of that?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here.. if the named cell's RefersTo contained a **UDF**, or another **Name** which has been stripped out *before* deleting names, this might cause this error..?

Comment: No problem. I have amended my original post with the image of the name manager from the workbook which is created by the copy macro. There's a lot of names in this thing (which is why we delete them) but none have an errored name.

Comment: There are no UDFs in this certain document but I can take a look for names containing names. But surely the fact that I am trying to just delete the thing rather than do any work with it should mean any of that wouldn't matter? I guess I'd have to ask that one guy at microsoft that probably works on maintaining the VBA functionality haha.

Comment: `The error that appears is below` - no, it's not. There is no actual error message anywhere. In any case, `Foreach` does not like when you modify the collection being enumerated. If you want to delete all names, use the `for` loop and index-based approach.

Comment: `Foreach` does not like when you modify the collection being enumerated. +1

Comment: Using 64bit office 2016 I can run 

      for each s in names:s.delete:next s

without error in the immediate window. So I'm not convinced it's the For Each that's the problem

Comment: It does seem to be specific to this workbook as it also works for me perfectly fine in other test on the same version... But this thing is so huge that I cannot just rebuild the workbook and test it. That would take a few days at least.

I am trying the enumeration that GSerg mentioned. Something like:

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nmCount As Integer

    nmCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count

    For i = 1 To nmCount
    ActiveWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
    Next i

Comment: Unfortunately the enumeration method using the above code (although instead of Names(i).delete I had to use Names(1) due to the shuffle down) results in the same error... Only other thing I can think it could be is a corruption somewhere. I really don't want to rebuild this thing!

Comment: @JaayB Of course you had to use `Names(1)` due to each operation changing the collection, that is the very same reason that sets the `foreach` off. You normally enumerate backwards when deleting, with `For i = nmCount To 1 Step -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my Windows profile had a corruption somewhere. The file also worked on other Windows 10 installations around the office. Re-installing Excel did not fix it, but rebuilding my Windows profile did. This is a first for me, and I thought I had seen everything already.

I would like to thank everyone who looked into this. I'm sure if this were a normal issue with Excel, the enumeration suggestion would have been spot on.